# Authorization Error Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: python

why this error comes  & how can i solved it :

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy

when i click on authorize url after that url opened in browser.

I am following  python Gmail API quickstart guide to authorize a user for the Gmail API. I've created a Web Application type app at Google console and generated it's credentials.json file. I've provided a redirect_uri .

When I run the quickstart.py.when i click on authorize url after that url opened in browser.

After I open the link in the browser it displays this error:-

https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/error?authError=ChVyZWRpcmVjdF91cmlfbWlzbWF0Y2gSsAEKWW91IGNhbid0IHNpZ24gaW4gdG8gdGhpcyBhcHAgYmVjYXVzZSBpdCBkb2Vzbid0IGNvbXBseSB3aXRoIEdvb2dsZSdzIE9BdXRoIDIuMCBwb2xpY3kuCgpJZiB5b3UncmUgdGhlIGFwcCBkZXZlbG9wZXIsIHJlZ2lzdGVyIHRoZSByZWRpcmVjdCBVUkkgaW4gdGhlIEdvb2dsZSBDbG91ZCBDb25zb2xlLgogIBptaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXJzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vaWRlbnRpdHkvcHJvdG9jb2xzL29hdXRoMi93ZWItc2VydmVyI2F1dGhvcml6YXRpb24tZXJyb3JzLXJlZGlyZWN0LXVyaS1taXNtYXRjaCCQAyomCgxyZWRpcmVjdF91cmkSFmh0dHA6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6ODA4MC8%3D&client_id=221990959960-40vsl59admu9j2v8lab1h7rgivo3o7ue.apps.googleusercontent.com

I'm unable to find why this issue coming.I want to call  Gmail API.

Created cloud account :-
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hls5P.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zHW0.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeMgf.png

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

```
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.json'):   
    creds =Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file( 'creds.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token: 
            token.write(creds.to_json())
service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: edited post with code . please check it.

Answer (score 0):

As the API has stated in error page, you may have mis-configured the redirect_uri of the login page.
Please sure that you're not having any typo related to"http"-"https". Last year I faced the same issue when setting up my login page and instead of using the URL with https, I entered an URL with http.

You also should double check the redirect_uri and make sure the login url has redirect_uri parameter. Without it, Google cannot recognize where will the login page to be redirected.

If that doesn't help, go to the console for your project and look under API Access. You should see your client ID & client secret there, along with a list of redirect URIs. If the URI you want isn't listed, click edit settings and add the URI to the list.

Comment: please check above edited post with redirect url .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating another Oauth 2.0 client ID (different from the one I was using within the same account). Just head to your [dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/), then:

1. Generate another ID.
2. Download `client_secret.json` and save it where the previous one
   was.
3. Name it as the previous one.
4. Now run the code again.